# How can I access hsql database through raw data files i.e. without an API or connector?

Tags: database, api, hsqldb, connector

I'm trying to access an hsqldb to render a web page with data from the hsqldb.
I cannot seem to find any means of accessing and reading the data from hsql database folders into a web page or other location.

The hsqldb folders is in the format .data, .properties, .script and .log consistently. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are supposed to be read using the HSQLDB jar. Please read the HSQLDB Guide.

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/